# Reflecting date difference in weeks based on selection instantly

Tags: php, html

Hello i have a form where user can enter their rental start date and end date. And from here, there will be a renting period field reflecting the difference between the rental start and end date instantly in the form of weeks

But i am stuck  on how to approach this. Anybody have an idea? 
Using HTML 5 input date btw.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="rental.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="pid" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" /><br>
       <strong>  Start Date: </strong><input type="date"  value="" /> <br>     
         <strong>  End Date: </strong> <input type="date"value=""/><br>   
            <strong>Renting Period: </strong> <input type="text"  value="" readonly> <br>                                                                                                              
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="button" value="Rent It"> 
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have it done client-side you have to use **javaScript**.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), also [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) will make this a lot easier, so that you can create a function that will be triggered [on change](http://api.jquery.com/change/).